Exercise on bounded sets in locally convex metrizable spaces
I'm stuck with the following exercise:
Let $(E,\mathcal{P})$ be a metrizable locally convex space. Show that for each sequence $(A_{n})_{n}$ of bounded subsets in $E$ there is a sequence of positive numbers $(\lambda_{n})_{n}$ such that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}A_{n}$ is bounded.
I've used the following definition of bounded set:
A subset $A$ of an locally convex space $(E,\mathcal{P})$ is said to be bounded if $\sup_{x\in A} p(x)<+\infty$ for every $p\in\mathcal{P}$ or, equivalently, if for each upper $U\in\mathcal{U}_{0}(E)$ there is $\lambda>0$ so that upper $A\subseteq\lambda U.$ We denote by $\mathcal{U}_{0}(E)$ the set of absolutely convex neighbourhoods of $0,$ and we are assuming $(E,\mathcal{P})$ is Hausdorff.
The ideas I have:
Since $E$ is metrizable then there exists a countable family $(p_{k})_{k}$ of seminorms. Now using the first definition of bounded set, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $A_{n}$ is bounded, thus $\sup_{x\in A_{n}} p_{k}(x)<+\infty.$
Therefore, there exists $M_{n,k}\geq0$ such that $\sup_{x\in A_{n}} p_{k}(x)\leq M_{n,k}.$ In fact, $M_{n,k}>0$ since if $M_{n,k}=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ then using Hausdorff condition $A_{n}=\lbrace0\rbrace$ and the result follows.
Thus, we define $\lambda_{n}:=\frac{1}{2^{n}M_{n,k}}>0$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ So now to see $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}A_{n}$ is bounded fix $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ If $x\in\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}A_{n}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in A_{n}$ and therefore $x=\lambda_{n}y$ for some $y\in A_{n}.$ Thus,
$$
p_{k}(x)=|\lambda_{n}|p_{k}(y)\leq\lambda_{n}M_{n,k}\leq\frac{1}{2^{n}},
$$
and it follows that $\sup_{x\in\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}A_{n}}p_{k}(x)<+\infty.$ Therefore, $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}A_{n}$ is bounded.
I believe the proof is not quite correct since $M_{n,k}$ given by the first bound and the one in the definition of $\lambda_{n}$ may not be the same, so I cannot cancel them. I've thought about taking $M_{n}$ (for a fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$) to be $\sup_{k}M_{n,k}$ and define $\lambda_{n}$ with $M_{n}$ instead. However, that supremum need not to be finite and then ensure to have $M_{n}>0$.
Perhaps the second definition of bounded set gives a different approach.
I would greatly appreciate any help or idea.

Yes! That is what I was looking for, thank you!

$\newcommand\la\lambda$Let
$$s_k(A):=\sup_{x\in A}p_k(x).$$
For each $n$, your condition that $A_n$ is bounded means that $s_k(A_n)\le M_{n,k}$ for some real numbers $M_{n,k}>0$ and all $k$.
Let now
$$\la_n:=1/\max_{j\le n}M_{n,j}.$$
Then for $n\ge k$ we have $k\le n$ and hence $\la_n M_{n,k}\le1$. So, for each natural $k$ and all natural $n$
$$\la_n M_{n,k}\le M_k:=\max(1,\max_{m\colon\, m<k}\la_m M_{m,k}). $$
So, for $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\la_n A_n$ and each $k$ we have
$$s_k(A)=\sup_{n\ge1}\la_n s_k(A_n)\le\sup_{n\ge1}\la_n M_{n,k}\le M_k<\infty; $$
That is, $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\la_n A_n$ is bounded. $\quad\Box$
